# Writing to a file from a Flask Server

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

I am writing a small application. pretty small one just to learn some new technologies.( angular -- front end) , Flask for server side . In the server, I have to store all the users info in a file. This file has all the usernames and passwords. 
I have tried this : ( But not working ):

```
    f=open('userinfo.txt','w')
    f.write(app.users)
    f.close()
```

here I store the username and the password in app.users which is a dictionary.

```
    app= Flask(__name__)

    app.users={}
```

These two lines show the dictionary part.

How can I store all the usernames and passwords in a file. How can I implement this. Help. any tutorials where I can learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing usernames and passwords in a file may not be the best idea however you cannot write a dictionary to a file you can only write strings to a file. For this example I will assume your `app.users` dictionary is in the format `{username: password}`

```
import os

with open('userinfo.txt', 'w') as users_file:
    for username, password in app.users.items()
        users_file.write(username + ',' + password + os.linesep)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't store account information in a file. Use sqlite, it is a server-less, transactional sql database that generates a single file (example.db).
Have a look on this tutorial: http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/